Configure react and express app for deployment leads to CORS policy error
I am trying to configure my react and express app for deployment and fix the problem of 404 errors when refreshing by following this:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/
I added:
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

-app.get('/', function (req, res) {
+app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });

and .htaccess
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

However, now I am getting this error. Why?
s.com/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s.com:4000/api/getcontent?page=0' from origin 'https://s.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

